# Finding $\iiint_K (x^2 -z^2)\, dx\, dy \,dz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Calculate the integral
>   $$
> \iiint_K (x^2 -z^2)\, dx\, dy \,dz\,,
> $$
>   where $$K=\left\{(x,y,z):x,y,z\ge 0,x+y+z\le 1\right\}$$

I have tried solving it but I really don't understand how to handle the upper limits. I really need some guidance.

Update:
I got it to zero by using it's symmetry as given in comments. Thanks for the help. I also confirmed it by calculating it myself with the values inputted.

Comment: I would start by sketching (drawing) the volume. It's a relatively simple shape ..

Comment: Why a sphere? The limits are all defined by flat planes. The plane
$$
x+y+z = 1
$$
Is a flat plane.

Comment: Oh, I see now, thanks. So, what is the next step?

Comment: The next step is to interpret the practical integration limits, looking at the picture.

Comment: Please show your work in the post, whatever you have tried.

Comment: fixed it (in question now)

Comment: No, the answer is zero, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Do not remove essential parts of the question. Accept answers if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

The region has an $xz$ exchange symmetry, i.e.

$$(x,y,z) \in K \implies (z,y,x) \in K$$

In other words

$$I = \iiint_K f(x,y,z)\:dV = \iiint_K f(z,y,x)\:dV$$

but in this problem for $f(x,y,z) = x^2-z^2$ we have that

$$f(z,y,x) = -f(x,y,z)$$

which means

$$I = -I \implies I = 0$$

Comment: @annie2000 I used a lot of shorthand at the end, but it is important for you to write out every step on your own that you don't understand rather than asking me to explain every small detail. For the last line, combine the previous two equations to see how that happens.

Comment: @annie2000 no, that's how a line integral works. Iterated integrals like this one don't split up like that.

Comment: okey, but how should I write out the boundaries?

Comment: @annie2000 this integral doesn't need boundaries written out to compute the answer. $I=-I$ by symmetry means $I = 0$